# How to Click all buttons on a page simultaneously one after one?

Tags: javascript

I have this code that clicks all buttons once.. what i want is to have a small delay 1 second after each button is clicked.. so not really at once, but simultaneously one after the other.... till all buttons are clicked!

here's the code:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('xxxxxxxx'); 

for (var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) 
{ 
    inputs[i].click(); 
}
```

Comment: `simultaneously one after the other` - sequentially is the word you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

> Use setTimeout()

Add set timeout on the third line of your code as shown below to click on every one second. Also, use `let` instead of `var` to make it work:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('xxxxxxxx'); 

for (let i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) // Use let not var to declare i
{ 
    setTimeout(inputs[i].click, i*1000);  // <<<<<< Here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ES6 is allowed you can one line this with map:

```js
const inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('xxx');
const clickButton = (btn) => btn.value = 'Clicked'

Array.from(inputs).map((x, i) => setTimeout(() => clickButton(x), i * 2000))
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="xxx" onclick="log()" />
<input type="submit" class="xxx" onclick="log()" />
<input type="submit" class="xxx" onclick="log()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion, instead of a for loop, and include a timeout in your function. Example:

```js
const inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('button'); 

const logClicked = () => console.log('clicked')

const checkTheBox = (arr,pos) => {
  if (pos < arr.length) {
    arr[pos].click()
    arr[pos].style.background = 'red'
    setTimeout(() => checkTheBox(arr, pos+1), 1000)
  }
  return
}

checkTheBox(inputs, 0)
```

```css
.button {
  border:1px solid black;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="submit" class="button" onclick="logClicked()" />
  <input type="submit" class="button" onclick="logClicked()"/>
  <input type="submit" class="button" onclick="logClicked()"/>
  <input type="submit" class="button" onclick="logClicked()"/>
  <input type="submit" class="button" onclick="logClicked()"/>
  <input type="submit" class="button" onclick="logClicked()"/>
  <input type="submit" class="button" onclick="logClicked()"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks.. it doesn't work buddy, it just clicks all buttons at the same time.
Btw, I am running the code on the console of the dev tools if it makes a difference.
Also it is a button not a checkbox..

Comment: Could be a browser issue. When you click "Run code snippet" under my answer that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Hi Fran, you example works great. What I am trying to click is a button, not a checkbox, please can you change the code accordingly?

Comment: Sure, <input type="button">, or <button> element?

Comment: <input type="submit" class="xxxxx" .......

Comment: I've updated it with input type submit, and it works when you run the code snippet.